# I'm getting "yum error no such table packages", how do I fix corrupted db?

Tags: linux, redhat, yum, rpm

I'm trying to use following guide: [Scientific Linux - How To Upgrade To The Latest S.L.  6.x Release](https://www.scientificlinux.org/documentation/howto/upgrade.6x) to update my Scientific Linux release 6.3 to Scientific Linux release 6.4.

```
# yum update --releasever=6.4 
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit, security
Error: no such table: packages
# cat /etc/redhat-release 
Scientific Linux release 6.3 (Carbon)
# uname -a
Linux XXXXX.XXXXX.XXX 2.6.32-358.18.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Aug 27 14:23:09 CDT 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
# rpm -q yum
yum-3.2.29-30.el6.noarch
#
```

I went through steps outlined in [Docs/RpmRecovery - rpm - Trac](http://www.rpm.org/wiki/Docs/RpmRecovery), still same results though...

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the plugins in scientific linux but in other yum distros you can run yum clean all. It will purge your yum cached files and refresh repository metadata. If your machine is having dns or repo config problems you will have to work through them.
See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21310/yum-cannot-retrieve-repository-centos-6

Comment: I've done "yum clean all" that didn't help my situation.